# Linear layout view to bitmap image view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

How to get bitmap image is same like about text view in linear layout
[image: img]

And my XML code is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textString" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: post your xml here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="textString" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> To convert text in textview to bitmap

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewid)
textview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
textview.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textview.getDrawingCache());
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

> To convert linearlayout to bitmap

```
LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutid);
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewid)
linearlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
linearlayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(linearlayout.getDrawingCache());
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

---

Pre-measure the view so that height and width don't remain null.

```
linearlayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
```

Assign a size and position to the view and all of its descendants

```
  linearlayout.layout(0, 0, linearlayout.getMeasuredWidth(), linearlayout.getMeasuredHeight());
```